# Javascript set operating timezone

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In one of our projects we would like to override the javascript mechanism of working with dates.
As we understand (from here - https://toastui.medium.com/handling-time-zone-in-javascript-547e67aa842d), the default behavior for browsers is to always work in local timezone.

Is there a way we can override that - meaning to set a default timezone and to know that independently of the local timezone, what we set there also hits the server with no timeconversion and in the time offset that we specify?

Example:
Desired timezone UTC + 2.
Localtimezone UTC + 10.
Create a date of 11/02/2021 8:30 AM, independent of the timezone on the browser, the date sent to the server will be 11/02/2021 8:30 AM UTC+2.